# Correct way to read tiff file in tensorflow using data reader

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tiff

I'm using tensorflow to read some geospatial image data which is in tiff format. I'd want to use something like:

```
    images = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=tf.string)
    img_contents = tf.read_file(images)
    img = tf.image.decode_image(img_contents, channels=3)
```

I guess what I need to do is to write a decoding function on my own. But img_contents is actually a tensor string that I cannot use it directly to access the file. Is there any way I can read the tiff image?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your file in Python, and pass to TensorFlow training graph by feed_dict, follow codes just for demonstration but is not runnable:

```
def read_tiff_file(file_path):
    #### code that read tiff_file content 
    return image_content # return the image content with 18 * 18 * 3

image_pl = tf.placeholder([18, 18, 3], tf.float32) # suppose your image is 18*18 with 3 channels

## constructing tf.graph with image_pl
## ...

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session as sess:
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        image_content = read_tiff_file(file_name)
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={image_pl:image_content})
```

Comment: Just wondering, is there any way I can continue using the dataReader with queue?

Comment: @QSMonk there isn't a tiff_decode, so I you should writing the op or it's impossible.